# Delete data from multi pal tables with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

***i want to delete a player from player table but it shows i have to delete foreign key data first***

```
Table structure for table matchinfo
Column  Type    Null    Default
matchinfo_id    int(11) No  
match_id    int(11) No  
match_info  longtext    No

Table structure for table matchplaying11
Column  Type    Null    Default
mp11_id int(11) No  
match_id    int(11) No  
team_id int(11) No  
player1 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player2 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player3 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player4 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player5 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player6 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player7 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player8 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player9 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player10    int(11) No  fk(player_id)
player11    int(11) No  fk(player_id)
captain int(11) No  fk(player_id)
vice_captain    int(11) No  fk(player_id)
wicket_keeper   int(11) No  fk(player_id)

Table structure for table matchscore_ball
Column  Type    Null    Default
msball_id   int(11) No  
match_id    int(11) No  
team_id int(11) No  
player_id   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
ball    int(11) No  
run int(11) No  
maiden  float   No  
wickets int(11) No  
economy int(11) No  
inning_1or2 int(11) No  

Table structure for table matchscore_bat
Column  Type    Null    Default
msbat_id    int(11) No  
match_id    int(11) No  
team_id int(11) No  
player_id   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
inning_1or2 int(11) No  
run int(11) No  
ball    int(11) No  
strike_rate int(11) No  
four    int(11) No  
six int(11) No  
wicket_by   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
caught_by   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
stumped_by  int(11) No  fk(player_id)
runout_direct   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
runout1 int(11) No  fk(player_id)
runout2 int(11) No  fk(player_id)

Table structure for table news
Column  Type    Null    Default
news_id int(11) No  
team_id int(11) No  
player_id   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
news_info   longtext    No  

Table structure for table player
Column  Type    Null    Default
player_id   int(11) No primary key  
player_name varchar(30) No  
player_country  varchar(30) No  
player_bday date    No  
player_type varchar(30) No  
batting_style   varchar(30) No  
bowling_style   varchar(30) No  
player_info longtext    No  

Table structure for table playerdebutlast
Column  Type    Null    Default
pdl_id  int(11) No  
player_id   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
t20_debut   varchar(30) No  
t20_lastplayed  varchar(30) No  
odi_debut   varchar(30) No  
odi_lastplayed  varchar(30) No  
test_debut  varchar(30) No  
test_lastplayed varchar(30) No  

Table structure for table playerteam
Column  Type    Null    Default
pt_id   int(11) No  
player_id   int(11) No  fk(player_id)
team1   int(11) No  
team2   int(11) No  
team3   int(11) No  
team4   int(11) No  
team5   int(11) No  
other_team  varchar(60) No
```

**
abpve are the tables and foriegn key mentioned as fk(player_id).

### so what query should i use to delete player from all table which have foreign key.

is it possible to delete in single query or should i use multipal queryies
**

Comment: What don't you understand?  You cannot delete a player that is on a team.

Comment: You can set the foregin key to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Or, you have to delete the dependancies first.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I cannot delete a player if it is used in playerteam table as foreign key so now if i want to delete player i have to firstly delete data from playerteam where player id is used as foreign key. So what wuery should i use to delete data from every table where player id i want to delete is used –

Comment: @Qirel ok can you please tell me the code to delete after CASCADE

Comment: After the foreign key created using "ON DELETE CASCADE", once the record deleted in the master table, it automatically deletes all related record from the child table.